# Default values for new rows added in slickgrid

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I have slickgrid with the enableAddRow option turned on.  However, when the user adds a new row, all of the values are set to undefined.  I'd like to be able to set a set of default values, but my searching has only turned up a mention of the option newRowDefault which doesn't seem to do anything and does not exist in slick.core.js or slick.grid.js.

It seems like this would be an easy thing to do... Is there any way to make a set of default values?

Comment: Put up an example on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  var newItemTemplate = {
    field1: value1,
    field2: value2
  };

  grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    var item = $.extend({}, newItemTemplate, args.item);
    dataView.addItem(item);
  });
```